# angular2 universal and nginx do not work well togeather

Tags: nginx, angular

I am having an issue serving angular2 universal with nginx.

My my root dir for the app I run the below:

`npm run build` to prepare a distributable bundle
`npm start` to build your client app and start a web server

Here is my nginx:

```config
server {

     listen 80 default_server;
     listen [::]:80 default_server;
     root /var/greenlabel-starter/src;

     # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
     index index.html index.htm index.php index.nginx-debian.html;

     #server_name example.net;

     location / {
         # First attempt to serve request as file, then
         # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
         try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
     }

     # Here we proxy pass only the base path
     location = / {
         proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
         proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:3000;
     }

         # Here we proxy pass all the browsersync stuff including
         # all the websocket traffic
    location /test {
         proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:3000;
         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
         proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
         proxy_set_header   Host $host;
     }
 }
```

problem is this:

http://test.com:8051/index.js 404

Is index.html

```
 <script src="/index.js"></script>
```

File is located in dist/server/index.js

How do I find the file so I dont get that error?